# Why we use GPIO for embedded systems?

Tags: electrical-engineering, embedded-systems, simulink

I'm using an F2802x microcontroller and I saw in Embedded Coder in Simulink that I have Digital output block. When I use this block, how does it work?

Comment: There seems to be a mismatch between the header and body. Also the way its beibg asked is incredibly broad. Please fix the question to something more understandable and manageable. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

**GPIO** stands for **G**eneral **P**urpose **I**nput **O**utput. Lets assume you want to generate a pulse at pin 39 as in the below image. So when you wire the pulse to pin 39 the underline software will generate the necessary code to configure pin 39 to be an output pin enabling the pin to output a pulse.

[image]

Below is the code stack between Simulink and Microcontroller. So when you create a Digital Output block the software will essentially convert and configure your Digital Output block into a Digital output pin. The code will convert into binary code to be able to loaded into the micro controller. Below is a high level diagram that explains the process.

[image]

---

**References:**

- [C2000 Digital Signal Controllers](http://focus.ti.com/download/tidc/pdfs/asia/2008/tw_T2_2_Joey_Chen_resized.pdf)
- [Embedded Coder Target for Energia](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/54929-embedded-coder-target-for-energia/content/html/TIVAgettingstarted.html)